# Redireccionar a diferentes Activity con Views

Tags: android

Buenas,
Estoy haciendo una App en la cual se se posesionan diferentes imágenes en forma de circulo, y en cada una de esas imágenes tiene que direccionar a una vista diferente.

Así es como se vería el App con las imágenes cargadas.

[image: Vista de App con las imágenes cargadas]

El problema viene cuando doy clic a alguno de las imágenes, ya que no importa cual seleccione siempre me direcciona a la ultima vista que cargué.

Para poner menos codigo lo que hice fue solamente poner dos imagenes que deberian direccionar a diferentes vistas.
Algo así:

[image: App con dos Imágenes]

El código cuando hago el `OnClickListener` seria este:

```
public void actionViews(){
   c0.setOnClickListener(this);
   c2.setOnClickListener(this);

   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   addContentView(c0, params);
   addContentView(c2, params);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v ==  c0){
        try{
            Intent intent = new Intent(inicio.this, ciclo.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }catch (Exception e){}
    }else if(v == c2()){
        try{
            Intent intent = new Intent(inicio.this, chat.class);
            startActivity(intent);
         }catch (Exception e){}
    }
}
```

En este caso lo que pasa siempre es que cuando le doy click a cualquiera de las dos imágenes, siempre direcciona al chat class.

El crear y cargar las imágenes lo hago en la misma clase de la siguiente forma:

```
static public class CircleView extends View implements View.OnClickListener {
Paint paint;
Object[] circulos;
Bitmap imagen;

//variables
float CX;
float CY;
float CR;

//tag
String btnTag = "";

public CircleView(Context context, float x, float y, float r, Bitmap img, String tag) {
    super(context);
    CX = x;
    CY = y;
    CR = r;
    imagen = img;
    paint = new Paint();
    btnTag = tag;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawBitmap(imagen, CX-(CR/2), CY-(CR/2), paint);
    this.setTag(btnTag);
}
```

Esto lo que hace simplemente es poner la imagen en los puntos (x,y) que le envío.

Si me pudieran ayudar les agradecería mucho.

Comment: No haz intentado crear las imagenes en tu layout con distintas id y en tu Activity obtener esas imagenes por su id y configurar un click para cada imagen?

Comment: Has agregado a los views sea LinerLayout o ImageView, agregar android:clickable="true"

Answer (score 0):

Si tu método anterior funciona con el de chat, y copiaste el código tal como lo tienes, puedo ver que te faltan unos paréntesis en el primer `if`, en el `c0`. Prueba con agregarlos, si no funciona, puedo ayudarte a modificar ese código para que manejes los clicks de forma diferente. Podrías usar un `switch`.

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v ==  c0()){
            try{
                Intent intent = new Intent(inicio.this, ciclo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }catch (Exception e){}
        }else if(v == c2()){
            try{
                Intent intent = new Intent(inicio.this, chat.class);
                startActivity(intent);
             }catch (Exception e){}
        }
```

Debeías agregar un **id** a tus botones y mediante el click accedas al `View` y compares el `View` con el *id* mediante un `switch`.

Comment: Buenas, Talvez el error sea que estas imágenes no son botones, ya que la función donde creo las imágenes es un View `static public class CircleView extends View` y al crearlas hago lo siguiente: `View c0 = new CircleView(...)`.

Comment: El problema no es un switch, sino que no importa a cual imagen le de click siempre me direcciona al ultimo view que agregue, en este caso el ultimo que agrego es el `c2 addContentView(c2, params);`, por lo que aunque le de en el otro view, igual direcciona al chat, para explicarme un poco mas, cuando entra al `OnClick` el `View v` que viene siempre es el mismo.

Comment: Tienes razón @dieroste. Solo comentaba que no estaba haciendo referencia a un View diferente.